# Web development displaying Images on top of Images

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a database an it storing x and y values and a boolean and I query the info with php
I want to display an image and on top of this image depending on the values from the database i want to display a red circle image for false and a green circle image for true on top of the first image depending on the x and y

I want to know what would be the best way to do this?
and for which language would it be the easiest to implement? css, html, php, javascript

Comment: Your answer for language choice is PHP, CSS, HTML. They all do something different - and in practice, there is no HTML without CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

displaying another image on your first image can easily be achieved with css. Control the z-index, position tag and top,left css tags for your images.  If you want to add any interaction, then u will have to use javascript as well.  And off course, HTML will be utilized because it will be structure of your site. So my ans will be HTML+CSS

Answer (score 1):

Best way would be to generate the correct CSS + HTML via PHP on the server side.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript + CSS is my suggestion for annotating an image and I recommend the [ZURB jQuery Plugin](http://zurb.com/playground/javascript-annotation-plugin) to do so.

This sample of ZURB seems to be very similar to what you are trying to accomplish:

```
$('#numberedNutmeg').addAnnotations(function(annotation){
    return $(document.createElement('span')).
    addClass('black circle note').html(annotation.position);
},[
    {x: 0.3875, y: 0.3246, position: 4}, 
    {x: 0.57, y: 0.329, position: 2}
  ]
);
```